# Lubuntu 14.04. Copy DVD between two DVD drives

Tags: lubuntu, dvd

I'm running Lubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I am a former Windows person.

I create a master document DVD and then I burn copies of it to a second DVD drive to send to my
co-workers. This is a frequent task.

I'm running LXDE and tried K3B but that just screwed up the
system because I think it is for KDE. Anyway Firefox and other
apps failed to start after using K3B.

I ended up having to reload the system from a backup image.

Anyone one know a program the will run under LXDE on Lubuntu?

Thank you

Comment: Please do not use derogatory terms to refer to other OS, It is unprofessional and detracts from Ubuntu.

Comment: I didn't mean to be unprofessional, but lighten up a little. I have been working with or on Unix / Linux since 1974.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brasero should work for you, you can open Brasero and select the option "Disc copy" on the left hand side of the window. Then select the input disc and the output disc and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Brasero works very good.  Thank you.  This should close this question.

Answer (score 0):

K3B uses Qt, but this doesn't mean that it is restricted purely to KDE. It should work in all window managers. As you don't mention specifics with regard to what problems you're experiencing with K3B I can't help you with that.

However, if K3B doesn't work for you, you can always use [AcetoneISO](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/acetoneiso/), being a suitable alternative to K3B in your case.

Comment: I have always found K3B to be most reliable, but you can certainly try others.

Comment: I tried Brasero but it wants media with audio tracks. Unless I am not using it correctly.  I installed it via apt-get install brasero.

Comment: Okay, I see - I have modified my answer to include AcetoneISO, which is probably what you're looking for